# Doxygen: Can't install .docset file to Xcode5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, doxygen

I've created a Doxygen docset for an Objective-C/C (no C++) project by running:

```
doxygen
```

. . . and then in the output dir:

```
make
```

This results in a file called MyProject.docset . . The file install fine in eg Dash.app, however it doesn't give me any documentation in Xcode. I've tried the following:

- Copy to ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Docsets
- Copy to /Applications/Xcode. . . . /Docsets
- Right-click, open with Xcode

According to Apple, the following documentation systems are fully supported:

- Headerdoc
- Doxygen

I've tried installing an Appledoc docset, and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's docset contents hierarchy you're talking about: Xcode 5 changed the metadata format for describing the nodes. In previous versions they used flat list of tokens.xml files but with Xcode 5 the format is folder structure with xml files as leafs. The result is docset that should still be searchable but not showing any nodes when browsing in Xcode docs sidebar. Dash still supports old format, so the docset looks fine there. As for appledoc, [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc/issues/409) covers it.

Comment: Hi Tomaz, the issue you refer to doesn't clearly indicate what was changed in Appledoc to solve the issue and isn't very conclusive on whether or not it actually worked. Can you point me to the code changes or explain with an example what was changed?

Comment: It's not solved yet, I just pointed to issue which tracks it (I was already interacting with Jasper on other issues so thought he might want to subscribe to this one to be notified of progress).